# How to download and set up a complete ledger for RPC endpoint

Tags: validator, rpc, ledger, bigtable

- I can set up a `bigtable` instance with steps specified  [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-bigtable).
- And I can set up an RPC endpoint with `solana-validator` CLI [here](https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start).

However, I do not understand from where I can download a complete ledger to populate said `bigtable` instance from a genesis block.

Comment: Just to add, there's a list of Solana RPC endpoint providers here https://solana.com/rpc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already [linked to the doc](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-bigtable#import-solanas-bigtable-instance) that explains how to do this.